# How to save budget list in local storage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I know local storage is not a secure solution for this, but for now, I am doing it this way for practice.

I think I am on the right track here, I want my created list for the budget app to store, this method seems to store the first created list.

```
/*----Store Stored budget list----*/
function storedEntry(){

const saveData = makeNewBudget();
const myJSON = JSON.stringify(saveData);
window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, myJSON); 
}
```

I think what needs to happen is get that same method to work for the array.

```
let budgetArray =  [];
```

I tried this method, but gives a JSON error, sop for some reason it's not converted to JSON

```
let budgetArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");
```

End result should be set local storage for array in its own function and get the stored information when checking the array.

I put the entire JS code so you can see what is going on

```
/*----Generate ID----*/

const createId = () =>`${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}$(new Date().getTime())}`;

/*----Get current Date----*/

function createdDate() {

  let currentDate = new Date();

  let day = String(currentDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  let month = String(currentDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  let year = currentDate.getFullYear();

  currentDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
  console.log(currentDate)
  return currentDate;
}


/*----Variable Objects----*/
const el = {
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  cashflow: document.querySelector("#cashflow"),
  catagory: document.querySelector(".catagory"),
  label: document.querySelector(".label"),
  number: document.querySelector(".number"),
};

/*----Array with local Storage----*/

let budgetArray =  [];

/*----Budget list Object----*/

function makeNewBudget(){
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    cashflowNew: el.cashflow.value,
    catagoryNew: el.catagory.value,
    labelNew: el.label.value,
    dateNew: createdDate(),
    numberNew: el.number.value,
  };
  return data;
}

/*----Render Budget List----*/
function renderList(){
el.list.innerHTML = budgetArray.map(function (data,i) {

  return `<div class="entry">
  <div class="list">
    <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="Archive" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/archive.png" alt="Archive">
      </button>
      <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/edit.png" alt="Edit">
      </button>

      <div class="input" data-id="${data.id}"></div>
      <label class="dateNew">${data.dateNew}</label>
      <label class="cashflowNew">${data.cashflowNew}</label>
      <label class="catagoryNew">${data.catagoryNew}</label>
      <label class="labelNew">${data.labelNew}</label>
      <label class="numberNew">${data.numberNew}</label>
  </div>
</div>
<label class="total"></label>`;
});



}

/*----form validation----*/
let budgetButton = document.querySelector(".budget-button");

let label = document.querySelector(".label");
let num = document.querySelector(".number");
let entry = document.querySelector(".entry")

budgetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

  if (!label.value || !num.value) {
    alert("please make sure all inputs are filled");
  }
  
  budgetArray.push(makeNewBudget())

  renderList();

  storedEntry();

});

/*----Archive list----*/
function deleteItem(event, i){
  
}

/*----Store Stored budget list----*/
function storedEntry(){

const saveData = makeNewBudget();
const myJSON = JSON.stringify(saveData);
window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, myJSON);

  
}
```

[image: Error I am getting]

Comment: I just tried `JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");` in the Chrome dev tools and it works fine, can you be more specific about the error you are running into?

Comment: Thanks @MatthewHerbst, the JSON error seems to have gone now, not sure what I did to cause that,but now I have a new issue.